# Reading $_POST variables

Tags: php, mysql, lua

Basically, I have some rows that look like the following image:

[image]

Each ExampleUser has an ID and that ID isn't going to change at all.

I need the sql to read what ever `$sentid` is set to. To better explain, I have this lua code. (The lua code is working perfectly fine)

```
HS:PostAsync("http://examplesite0wwa/PresCand.php","sentid="..script.Parent.ExampleUser1.USERD.Value, 2)
```

And this sends as `Variabel1 = Data1`

And then I have this sql code.

```
<?php
    $vote = $_POST["votes"];
    $sentid = $_POST["sentid"]
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","anexapleomf1","","my_anexapleomf1");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `my_anexapleomf1`.`President Candidates` SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = $sentid";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error updating record: <br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

And what this should be doing, is reading what ever the sent `$sentid` was, and 
then setting the `$sentid` in WHERE, buuut it's not doing that.

**An example of this would be if $sentid was sent with the value of 2, and then the**

```
WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = $sentid
```

would be read as

```
WHERE `President Candidates`.`id` = 2
```

Comment: what are you facing ? 'buuut it's not doing that' bit unclear

Comment: What do you get on the page if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have any problem of reading the post variable in your code, try to echo the post variable to see if it has been posted effectively, if not, check out the action method of your form.